# Arbitrary write vulnerability without buffer overflow

Tags: c++, c, security, buffer-overflow, memory-safety

I was diving into memory vulnerabilities (C/C++) and I am interested in knowing what kind of vulnerabilities allow an arbitrary memory write (or read) without exploiting a buffer overflow (or overread). The ultimate goal would be to reach an arbitrary location (target) exploiting a memory vulnerability (source), without accessing the memory between the target and the source. It doesn't matter if the location can be choosen, I'm only interested in the ability of reaching a distant location.

I know a possible example would be the use of the %n placeholder in the printf functions and similar (format string vulnerability). Are there any other?

I also know that corrupting an index somehow (maybe integer overflow) might lead to such an arbitrary write, like in the following example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int c = atoi(*(argv+1)); //get value from input
    char buf[40000];    
    if(c>39999) return 1; //check boundary for buffer
    short ind = c; //wrong conversion --> integer overflow
    buf[ind] = 'c'; //Write to arbitrary location (negative index)
}
```

However, I wonder if there are more classical examples of such vulnerabilities. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The code `return buffer[index]` might be exploited to read an arbitrary location in memory and it wouldn't necessarily read "the memory between the target and the source".

Comment: Expect hurdles all the way, It is the task of the operating system to not allow you to read/write memory that does not belong to your process (and that's a good thing crashing your own programs is bad enough).  Kind of curious what do you want to do with this?

Comment: Unless they're in the kernel, buffer overflow vulnerabilities don't involve accessing memory that doesn't belong to your process. But they can still be damaging, e.g. as virus vectors, or exploiting bugs in daemon code that affects multiple users, etc.

Comment: actually `short ind = c` is not an overflow. the behavior is implementation defined.

Comment: For those wondering it's for research purposes. And to clarify, I'm not interested in accessing memory outside of the process, rather memory not adjacent to the buffer

Answer (score 1):

Simply set a pointer to an arbitrary address and indirect through it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int argc, char ** argv){
    char *c = (char *)strtoul(*(argv+1), NULL, 0); //get value from input
    *c = 'c';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This construct does indeed give arbitrary write, but I reckon that it is the goal of the program. What I'm looking for are vulnerabilities that allow this kind of behaviour as a side-effect of the program.

Comment: Real-world vulnerabilities are most often due to buffer overflows when reading data.

Comment: Because it's unusual to receive array indexes or pointers from untrusted sources.